# PHP - Read TXT from specific position

Tags: php, parsing, text, position

I'm having trouble with PHP text parsing
I have a txt file which has this kind of information:

> sometext::sometext.0 = INTEGER: 254

What i need is to get the last value of 254 as variable in PHP.
in this txt file this last value can change from 0 to 255

"sometext::sometext.0 = INTEGER: " this part doesn't change at all.
It has a length of 36 symbols, so i need get with PHP what is after 36 symbol into variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php):

```
$string = "sometext::sometext.0 = INTEGER: 254";    
sscanf($string, "sometext::sometext.0 = INTEGER: %d", $number);
echo $number;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Ash2QHvI

Comment: @user1466766 no problem ^_^`sscanf` is a very powerful tool :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [substr()](http://php.net/substr) will do?

```
$text = "sometext::sometext.0 = INTEGER: 254";    
print substr($text, 37);
```

See it in action here (adjusted to match your sample data): http://codepad.org/5Ikt3kRh

Comment: The problem with that is that you have to recalculate the length every time.

Comment: The OP said "this part doesn't change at all. It has a length of 36 symbols".

Comment: Running the code as shown above prints nothing, since `substr()` starts after the end of `$text`.

Comment: @GreenMatt - Yes, and that's why I included a codepad.org sample, which as I mentioned was adjusted to match the sample data.  Perhaps you missed the OP's statement that his actual data "**has a length of 36 symbols**" before the data he's interested in turns up.

Comment: @ghoti:  As is obvious in my answer, I didn't miss the OP's statement about the length.  Also I saw that your codepad example uses the proper starting point.  However, all this isn't obvious in the answer, and I suspect that not everyone is going to follow that link.  Just trying to be helpful here, sorry if I caused offense.

Answer (score 1):

Try [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) for reading a file.

For the parsing I use *split*. I wrote an [example](http://codepad.org/JbLxWJbc) here. But sscanf seems to be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the string is always going to be of that form you can use the [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to extract the part of the string you want.  Then use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to make it an integer if needed.

Note:  My count shows that the number you're trying to get starts at the 33rd position (which becomes 32 below, as substr is 0 based), not the 36th.

You can get what you want with:

```
$the_str = 'sometext::sometext.0 = INTEGER: 254';
$num = intval(substr($the_str, 32));
```